# Is it possible to "group" a Views field when using the "Content" display format?

Tags: views

We have a View using the Content display format (not Fields) because we're using a theme template to output the nodes. This works great but we also need to group to nodes by a field on the node (category). When using the Fields display output for a View it gives you the "group by" field option but (for obvious reasons) not when using the Content display format.

Is there a workaround to allow grouping Nodes by a field (category) when using View's Content display formats?

[image]
D9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can use the "rendered entity" as a field. You need to:

- Switch the Formate -> show to fields
- In the fields section, add a new "rendered entity" field
- You can then activate the "Group by" function
  [image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I thought there may be a workaround and I was not aware of the Rendered Entity field.